# Help for function continuity exercise

Tags: limits, functions, limits-without-lhopital

I have to verify the continuity of this function and I don't really understand anything...

Here it is (sorry but I don't know the specific text formatting so it's gonna be raw):
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 + 2^{1 / (x-1)} & x < 1 \\
1 & x \geq 1
\end{cases}
$$
Verify continuity for $a = 1$.

Also this:
$$ f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
e^{-(1 / (x+1)^2)}  & x \neq 2 \\
0 & x = 2
\end{cases}
$$

Verify continuity for $a = 2$.

Please explain as well as you can. How is the first one not $1+2^\infty= \infty$ ? The answers at the end of the book is $0$ I think.

Comment: In the first one consider a limit from the right of 1 (so that x = 1+h and let h go to 0) and a limit from the left of 1 (so that x =1 -h and let h go to 0) separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function is continuous if the left limit is equal to the right limit and it is equal to the function value evaluated at the point.

$$f(1) = 1$$
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 1^+} 1 = 1$$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 1^+} 1+2^{\frac1{x-1}} = 1+2^{\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-}\frac1{x-1}}=1+2^{-\infty}=1$$

Hence it is continuous.

For the second function.

$$f(2)=0$$
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2}\exp\left(-\frac1{(x+1)^2}\right)=\exp\left( -\frac19\right) \neq 0$$

Hence it is not continuous.